# Calculations inside for loop with variables that differ only in the last index number of their name ,in R

Tags: r, indexing, paste

I have the following code. I wish to assign to the `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4` variables certain calculations wish need to be done with the `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4` variables. So instead of doing the calculations four times i tried doing it with a for loop.

In the for loop i tried assigning  the `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4` variables  to an `m` variable that would later do the calculations needed for the variables `i1` through `i4`.

However a problem arises when using the `paste()` function, since it returns a character and not the variable.

Questions :

1.How do i use the paste function to return a variable?

2.If not possible, how can i proceed to do several calculations with variables that differ only in the last number.

```
B_zap <- 3
L_zap <- 4.5

B <- 1.5
L <- 2.25
z <- 3


(m1 <- B / z)
(n1 <- L /z)

(m2 <- (B_zap - B) / z)
(n2 <- L /z)


(m3 <- (B_zap - B) / z)
(n3 <- (L_zap - L) / z)


(m4 <- B / z)
(n4 <- (L_zap - L) / z)


for(i in 1:4) {

m <- paste("m", i, sep = "")
n <- paste("n", i, sep = "")

(i1 <- 2 * m *n * (m^2 +n^2 +1) ^0.5 )
(i2 <- m^2 + n^2 +(m^2 * n^2) + 1)
(i3 <- m^2 + n^2 +2)
(i4 <- i3-1)


}
```

Comment: You might be looking for `get()` as `i=1; get(paste0("m", i))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a for loop, you could take advantage of R's vectorization and put this all into dataframes.

First you can put the quantities you want into a dataframe with `m` and `n` columns, defined the way you have them in your example.

```r
library(dplyr)

B_zap <- 3
L_zap <- 4.5

B <- 1.5
L <- 2.25
z <- 3

df <- data_frame(m = c(B / z, (B_zap - B) / z, (B_zap - B) / z, B / z),
                 n = c(L /z, L /z, (L_zap - L) / z, (L_zap - L) / z))
```

Then you can use `mutate()` to make new columns that calculate the new quantities you are interested in that depend on the quantities you already have.

```r
df %>%
    mutate(index = row_number(), 
           i1 = 2 * m *n * (m^2 +n^2 +1) ^ 0.5,
           i2 = m^2 + n^2 +(m^2 * n^2) + 1,
           i3 = m^2 + n^2 +2,
           i4 = i3 - 1)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>       m     n index       i1       i2     i3     i4
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   0.5  0.75     1 1.009718 1.953125 2.8125 1.8125
#> 2   0.5  0.75     2 1.009718 1.953125 2.8125 1.8125
#> 3   0.5  0.75     3 1.009718 1.953125 2.8125 1.8125
#> 4   0.5  0.75     4 1.009718 1.953125 2.8125 1.8125
```